# use tshark/wireshark to examine local ip6 traffic

Tags: networking, ipv6, wireshark

I'm trying to debug a piece of software which listens for CoAP traffic over ip6. Normally, when the software is running in production / staging (i.e. on a server separate from the clients using it), I can just use tshark to intercept the CoAP traffic:

```
sudo tshark -i tap0 -f "udp port 5683"
```

When running this locally, however, I am unable to see any traffic at all with

```
sudo tshark -i lo -f "udp port 5683"
```

The only traffic I do see, is if I put the wrong port in my client (in which case I see some traffic but the client is unable to connect to the server).

Is there a way for me to examine the local CoAP traffic over ip6?

Comment: Are you sure the traffic does actually go via `lo`? Can you see it with the filter disabled?

Comment: As you suggested, I played around with the filter off and it was because of the udp port being on 5683 instead of 9084 that I was missing things. This has always been a bit confusing because of the way production was set up but I'm now seeing the packets.